# How do you get buttons to be aligned by their borders rather than their text?

Tags: html, css

I have some stylized circular buttons, and I've noticed that, when displayed inline with other elements, they're aligned as though they are nothing but text.  The text "button" is aligned with the image in my example, but the actual area of the button hangs below.  This not only looks weird and seems unintuitive, but it pushes down the bottom margin of the entire line of elements!

I've tried several things to get the bottom edge of the button to align with the bottom edge of the image, but nothing is working.  This does not seem like it should be a difficult problem.

```css
button {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  border: outset 8px #999; 
  border-radius: 64px;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG/312px-RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG" height="100" width="auto">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `vertical-align: bottom;` on the `img` tag.

```css
button {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  border: outset 8px #999; 
  border-radius: 64px;
}
img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG/312px-RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG" height="100" width="auto">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to vertical alignment. Your image and button are both vertically aligned to the baseline (the default), which sets the button's text to the baseline of the container which, unfortunately, causes it to drop below the bottom of the image.

If you draw a line below the bottom of the text and the bottom of the image, you'd see they line up: their baselines are the same.

The image is the culprit here. Setting `vertical-align: bottom` on your image will do the trick.

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/) has a good write-up of these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can centrally align both with this snippet.

**CSS:**

```
button {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  border: outset 8px #999; 
  border-radius: 64px;
  vertical-align:40px;
}
img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button>button</button> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG/312px-RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG" height="100" width="auto">
```

take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r4njt6q5/)